# What's the difference between `pullFrom` and `connect` in purescript-coroutines?

Tags: coroutine, purescript

I'm not sure I understand the reason why there is a `connect` and a `pullFrom` function in [purescript-coroutines](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-coroutines/3.1.0/docs/Control.Coroutine), and when you would use both of them.  Looking at the types, it seems like they're used to the change the "direction of communication" (I'm not sure if that's the right way of thinking about it).

```
pullFrom :: forall o m a. MonadRec m => Consumer o m a -> Producer o m a -> Process m a

connect :: forall o f m a. (MonadRec m, Parallel f m) => Producer o m a -> Consumer o m a -> Process m a
```

So if I have a consumer and a producer...

```
consumer :: forall e a. (Show a) => Consumer a (Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e)) Unit
consumer = forever do
  s <- await
  lift (log $ show s)

numberProducer :: forall m. (Monad m) => Producer Int m Unit
numberProducer = go 0
  where
  go i = do emit i
            go (i + 1)
```

It makes sense to me that the consumer can pull from the producer, and if I run this, I can see the numbers being shown...

```
main = do
  runProcess (pullFrom consumer numberProducer)
```

But if I `connect` the producer to the consumer, it doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm assuming when you connect the producer to the consumer, the signaling is going in the opposite direction from `pullFrom`, but I'm not sure if that idea is correct.

```
main = do
  runProcess (connect producer consumer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this has a fun little surprise in it... I'll come to that in a minute though.

`pullFrom` was introduced so that the consumer is "in charge" when a process is formed - the process exists for as long as the consumer is open (awaiting an input).

`connect` runs as long as either the producer or consumer are open, and the process only terminates when they both complete.

To achieve this, `connect` has a `Parallel` class constraint, as the created process depends on both consumer and producer - `pullFrom` does not require this, since the process is dependent only on the `consumer`.

This is where the "fun" surprise comes in - and confused me for a minute. `Eff` is not `Parallel`... so how does your code work? It's because it's inferring this type for `main`:

```
main :: forall t. (Parallel t (Eff (console :: CONSOLE))) => Eff (console :: CONSOLE) Unit
```

So nothing happens when your program is run, because in the JS, `main` is expecting a dictionary to be passed for the `Parallel` constraint, then the `Eff` to be evaluated. The generated call to main is just `Main.main();`, so it never actually evaluates the `Eff`, as it would need to be `Main.main(impossibleParallelDictionary)();`.

Try adding this type to your `main`:

```
main :: Eff (console :: CONSOLE) Unit
```

And you'll see that it doesn't type check anymore.

You can use `Aff` for this though, and with `Aff` the difference between `connect` and `pullFrom` is indistinguishable for this example:

```
import Prelude

import Control.Coroutine (Consumer, Producer, await, connect, emit, runProcess)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff, launchAff)
import Control.Monad.Aff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION)
import Control.Monad.Rec.Class (forever)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

consumer :: forall e a. (Show a) => Consumer a (Aff (console :: CONSOLE | e)) Unit
consumer = forever do
  s <- await
  lift (log $ show s)

numberProducer :: forall m. (Monad m) => Producer Int m Unit
numberProducer = go 0
  where
  go i = do emit i
            go (i + 1)

main :: Eff (err :: EXCEPTION, console :: CONSOLE) Unit
main = void $ launchAff $ runProcess (connect numberProducer consumer)
```

If we modify the example slightly, we can see an illustration of the difference:

```
import Prelude

import Control.Coroutine (Consumer, Producer, await, emit, connect, runProcess)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff, launchAff, later')
import Control.Monad.Aff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

consumer :: forall e a. (Show a) => Consumer a (Aff (console :: CONSOLE | e)) Unit
consumer = do
  s <- await
  lift (log $ show s)

numberProducer :: forall eff. Producer Int (Aff eff) Unit
numberProducer = do
  emit 0
  lift $ later' 10000 $ pure unit

main :: Eff (err :: EXCEPTION, console :: CONSOLE) Unit
main = void $ launchAff $ runProcess (connect numberProducer consumer)
```

With this, the program will print 0, wait 10 seconds, and quit. If you switch `connect numberProducer consumer` out for `` consumer `pullFrom` numberProducer `` the program will print 0 and exit immediately.

Comment: Thanks, gb, that makes sense!  Could you clarify the note about "connect runs as long as either the producer or consumer are open, and the process only terminates when they both complete."  Should that say "terminates when either complete"?  It seems like if I make a consumer that only awaits one value (i.e. I remove `forever` from the consumer function above), that the numberProducer would still be "open" and keep the process open.

Comment: I've edited another example into the answer that lets you observe the difference between `pullFrom` and `connect`. I think my description of "open" might not be the best way of phrasing it - in my description the producer is "open" when the function for an "emit step" has not yet completed. So even if you have an infinite producer and a finite consumer the process still ends when the consumer is done (or vice versa) with `connect`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra example, that makes sense now.